# A 'mix' of simple and lazy simple random walk

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a $\mathbb{Z}$ valued markov chain $X_n$ which evolves as follows.

$$P(X_{n+1}=y | X_n) =\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}, y=X_n+1, X_n-1,  |X_n|>K \\ 
\frac{1}{4}, y = X_n-1 , y= X_n+1, |X_n|\leq K\\
\frac{1}{2}, y=X_n,|X_n|<K
\end{cases}, $$

where $K>0$.

Basically, $X_n$ behaves like lazy simple random walk in $[-K,K]$ and simple random walk outside $[-K,K]$.

I am puzzled by the following inequality. 
$$P_0(X_n=y)\leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}, \forall y$$
where $C$ is a constant independent of $y$ ,$P_0$ means the chain start at $0$.

I don't know how to approach this problem, the method for simple random walk  which is basically binomial distribution does not work here.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Would you know how to prove this for the fully lazy random walk (the case K = +oo, so to speak)?

Comment: @Did, Thanks, I am able to prove it now, using characteristic function and the inversion formula for discrete random variable and Laplace's method.